# Can peridynamics give accurate quantitative results?

Tags: computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

I'm applying for a position that is interested in studying crack growth using peridynamics. I have experience with MD on polymeric systems, but I had never knew of this method before. It seems very well suited for at least qualitative description of cracks.

My concern is: can it also provide quantitative results? Crack growth and propagation is not a trivial task to model!

Comment: For what types of materials? What spatial scales? Does time accuracy matter to you or only the final states? Have you looked at recent reviews of the approach?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have not been told explicitly what the materials will be, but I've inferred its for composite materials. I don't think they've given "time accuracy" much thought, but I think it's crucial. Finally, I'm still studying the fundamentals of the method, and have not read up on the cutting edge.